# Kill a function after another function has been run

Tags: javascript

I am making a dislike/like system where it displays when you liked or disliked something on the screen after you clicked on the image input.

My problem is, for example:

When I click on thumbs up a `LIKED` message appears like it should, but then I click the thumbs downs and the `DISLIKED` appears under the `LIKED`.

I would like it to be that if I click on the thumbs down then the `LIKED` message disappears and the `DISLIKED` appears.

```js
function ai() {
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "LIKED";
}

function aii() {
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "DISLIKED";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="liked"></h1>
<h1 id="disliked"></h1>
<input type="image" src="tu.png" class="tu" onclick="ai()">
<input type="image" src="td.png" class="td" onclick="aii()">
```

Comment: May I know why the vote down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create only 1 element and do it like following

```js
function ai() {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "LIKED";
}

function aii() {
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "DISLIKED";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="message"></h1>
<input type="image" src="tu.png" class="tu" onclick="ai()">
<input type="image" src="td.png" class="td" onclick="aii()">
```

Or you can improve your code like below

```js
function ai() {
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "LIKED";
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "";
}

function aii() {
  document.getElementById("disliked").innerHTML = "DISLIKED";
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<h1 id="liked"></h1>
<h1 id="disliked"></h1>
<input type="image" src="tu.png" class="tu" onclick="ai()">
<input type="image" src="td.png" class="td" onclick="aii()">
```

Comment: If you intend to use two elements, I would recommend showing and hiding them, instead.

Comment: Easy Fix! Thanks

Comment: @Haroldo_OK - That can also be a solution. Improving the solution in the same direction as OP. Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: @NiborCode - Glad to help you!

Comment: @Haroldo_OK I certainly agree :)

Answer (score 1):

Show and hide instead - Do be aware that type="image" is a submit button if inside a form:

Version 1: only one H1

```js
function ai(img) {
  console.log(img.className)
  document.getElementById("liked").innerHTML = img.className == "tu" ? "LIKED" : "DISLIKED";
  document.getElementById("liked").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.like {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<h1 class="like" id="liked"></h1>
<img src="tu.png" class="tu" onclick="ai(this)" />
<img src="tu.png" class="td" onclick="ai(this)" />
```

Version 2  - both on page:

```js
function ai(img) {
  console.log(img.className)
  document.getElementById(img.className == "tu" ? "liked" : "disliked").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(img.className == "tu" ? "disliked" : "liked").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.like {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<h1 class="like" id="liked">LIKED</h1>
<h1 class="like" id="disliked">DISLIKED</h1>
<img src="tu.png" class="tu" onclick="ai(this)" />
<img src="tu.png" class="td" onclick="ai(this)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ai(temp) {
  if (temp == "1") {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "LIKED";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "DISLIKED";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="Result"></h1>

<input type="image" src="tu.png" class="tu" onclick="ai(1)">
<input type="image" src="td.png" class="td" onclick="ai(0)">
```

Comment: A ternary would be more elegant